# Dividing a string into elements in a stucture

Tags: c++

I have a text file which contains lines that look like this:

```
string, int  string
```

and i am trying to divide each line into 3 elements that are sent to a structure.
Here what my code looks so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct address
{
 string street;
 int zip;
 string city;
};
istream & operator >>(istream & in, address & add)
{
 getline(in, add.street);
 getline(in, add.zip);
 getline(in, add.city);
}
```

Any advice or help would be appreciated, thanks in advance :D

Comment: can strings contain newlines? otherwise take first string with delimiter set as `','`. Then extract int with cin and remaining string with getline with `'\n'`

Comment: Each line has the same motiv. String(comma) int (double space) string

Answer (score 0):

Since the strings are so consistent this would be a perfect place for a [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/) call.

Comment: That's too complicated for me pal :)